# How to alter the column name in a table from front end?

Tags: sql-server

In my database I have a table with columns col1,col2,col3.

I want to give the fourth column i.e..,`col4` from the front end(when I click add column button in my front end).

Now the updated table should be like `col1,col2,col3,col4` after altering the fourth column.

Is it possible to alter a column from Frontend? If possible what is the stored procedure/query for that?

Comment: You mean you want to add a new column in a table. Use [ALTER TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at [alter table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) ddl statement.

Comment: Why would you want to allow an end user to dynamically add columns to your database??? This seems like a horrible idea that is going to be even worse to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

From the `front-end`, you can send the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

For more information on simple *Alter* statement, , click here:
[SQL ALTER TABLE STATEMENT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp)

Hope. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.doc_exy ALTER COLUMN column_a DECIMAL (5, 2) ;
```

Comment: This might be an answer to the question, but add description to avoid deletion.